# Saving & Reading a OpenCV Mats

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing

I need to save several progressions of Mats (colored image, inverted, etc...). Currently I'm struggling to find out how to save these efficiently whether it be to;

1. Save all progression as images and store them in a folder (Could Get out of hand fast)
2. Save the Mat to a txt/CSV file somehow then read that string data back in when needed.

If anyone has any insight and could provide examples it would be much appreciated. I know this is going to be one of my major features so it's important I get this right. Any suggestions I will give a shot so feel free to throw anything you think might work out.

**Here is some of the code I'm using to define the mats needing to be saved**

```
// Question Number, Question in color, Question inverted, Question Final, Final Bubbles
Dictionary<int, Tuple<Mat, Mat, Mat, List<Mat>>> questions = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<Mat, Mat, Mat, List<Mat>>>();
for (int questionNumber = 0; questionNumber < ColorQuestionMats.Count(); questionNumber++)
{
    questions.Add(questionNumber + 1, new Tuple<Mat, Mat, Mat, List<Mat>>
    (
        ColorQuestionMats[questionNumber],
        InvertedQuestions[questionNumber],
        finalQuestionMat[questionNumber],
        finalBubbles
    ));
}
```

Comment: matrices for any kind of arithmetic, or _images_? both are represented by `cv::Mat`. what size, i.e. width and height?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Small maybe 50 x 250 max. The Bubbles might have between 7-9 50x50 images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to go with this dictionary and only save the images needed for later use to a folder. The name of the save would included the question number so I could reference it in a json save I had. There were two different ways we could save the images, a Static and Dynamic file save amount.

The math worked out like; 
**Static** -> 47 (Locations) x 10 (Tests) x 700 (AVG People per Location) x 50Kb (Size of save) = 16,450,000Kb -> 16.45 Gb

***This Method assumes all people have this many questions bad, some may not have any. This also doesn't factor in test with more than 24 questions.*** 
**Dynamic** -> 47 (Locations) x 10 (Tests) x 700 (AVG People per Location) x (3Kb (Size of save) x 24 (Bad Question Answers we save)) = 
24 Bad = 23,688,000Kb -> 23.69Gb 
10 Bad = 9,860,000Kb -> 9.86Gb 
2 Bad = 1,974,000Kb -> 1.97Gb

The Static held less space in a long run, but since for my purpose the amount of bad questions may actually only be like max 6 in worst case scenarios, I went with Dynamic so I only stored the bad sections I needed.

```
Bitmap bitimg;
using (var ms = ColorQuestionMats[BQ].ToMemoryStream())
{
    bitimg = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
}
// Save the bitmap
bitimg.Save(MainWindow.FolderPath_BadAnswers + @"\" + MainWindow.curLocation + @"\" + MainWindow.curTT + @"\Q" + (questionNumber + 1) + "_BadAnswer.png");
```